# Problem with creating header and sorting data in Python

Tags: python, csv, sorting, header

I am creating a file that inputs grades and names, but I have 2 problems: 
I cannot define the header for the data, and when I sort my table, it gets sorted as lists but I would like to display it as a table: 
here is my code. when I try to save it, it only saves the first row of my table. How can I save all the sorted table in csv?

```
import csv
import operator
import pandas as pd


with open('Grade_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as stdFile:
    writer = csv.writer(stdFile)
    writer.writerow(["Last Name", "First Name", "Grade"])
    writer.writerow(["Potter", "Harry",6.5])
    writer.writerow(["Granger", "Hermione",11])
    writer.writerow(["Weasley", "Ron",6])


action = input("Would you like to read, write, or sort data in this file?")

if action == "read":
    fileObj = open("Grade_list.csv","r")
    print(fileObj.read())


elif action == "write": 
  nbStudents= float(input("How Many Student Records would you like to add? "))
  i = 0
  while i<nbStudents:
      with open('Grade_list.csv', 'a', newline='') as stdFile:
        writer=csv.writer(stdFile)
        writer.writerow([input("Please Provide the Last Name of the student: "), input("Please Provide the First Name of the student : "), float(input("Please Provide Grade of the student: "))])
        i = i+1


elif action =="sort":
  fileObj = open("Grade_list.csv","r")
  action2= input("Would you like to sort the data based on Last Names or Grades? ")
  if action2=="names":
    df = pd.read_csv('Grade_list.csv')
    df = df.sort_values(by=['Last Name'])
    print(df)

  elif action2=="grades":
    df = pd.read_csv('Grade_list.csv')
    df = df.sort_values(by=['Grade'], ascending=False)
    print(df)
    savingFile= input("Would you like to save the sorted list?")
    if savingFile=="yes":
      savingAction=input("Would you like to save your sorted list as a new file, or would you like to overwrite the exisiting file? Answer new to save in a new file, and overwrite to save your sorted file in the exisitng list ")
      if savingAction=="new":
        with open('Grade_list2.csv', 'w', newline='') as stdFile2:
          writer=csv.writer(stdFile2)
          writer.writerow(df)
      elif savingAction=="overwrite":
        with open('Grade_list.csv', 'w', newline='') as stdFile:
          writer=csv.writer(stdFile)
          writer.writerow(df)

    elif savingFile=="no":
      print("OK, Bye!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display it as table then `pandas` is your best option.

```
import pandas as pd
```

and then replace your code for sorting and displaying with below like:

```
  if action2=="names":
    df = pd.read_csv('Grade_list.csv')
    df = df.sort_values(by=['Last Name'])
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
Would you like to sort the data based on Last Names or Grades? names
  Last Name First Name  Grade
1   Granger   Hermione   11.0
0    Potter      Harry    6.5
2   Weasley        Ron    6.0
```

Have a look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library, you'll love it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It worked amazingly well for sorting. But I just have a final question, if I may: when I try to save the output, it only saves the first row. Is there a wat to solve the whole sorted table?

Comment: You can easily write the pandas dataframe to csv by `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')`
If the answer has helped you please do not forgot to accept it